# I want an operation that keeps digits in order and result in a year number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I remember a math teacher wishing us a good year with a mail title that was something like:

101 = (1 + 2 + 3)* 4 - 5*(6 - 7) + 8*9

Except the result was 2006.

Is there a website that can find a number this way, or is there some kind of script that does this already?

I'm curious about how this could be called. Number targeting game? I guess I could find it by brute force with a python eval() but placing parenthesis looks like it's quite a bit of work.

I guess it's still a fun curiosity to share. Is there a method other than brute force?

2021 is 43 x 47, so I'm not sure it's doable by hand.

What makes it beautiful is that the number are in order. Someone suggested:

1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 7 * 8 * 9 / 6 + 5

but it's not ordered.

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15021/862)

Answer (score 0):

$$-1\times 2+345\times 6-7\times 8+9=2021$$

And, for next year,

$$1- 2+345\times 6-7\times 8+9=2022.$$

However, I don't have a general method! Noticing that $345\times 6$ is reasonably close means one then has lots of options to adjust the answer using the other numbers.

Comment: I like this answer but the lack or operators between 345 bothers me a little...

Comment: I found -1 + 2 + 3 - 4 * (5 - 6) * (7 * 8 * 9)

Comment: A long time ago I wrote a program (in BBC basic) to generate solutions to things such as the Four 4s problem inserting symbols in $4444$. As I remember, the program was recursive in that it proceeded by choosing (successively) an adjacent pair of numbers. These two numbers  were then  combined  in an allowed manner and then one had one fewer number.